# useDispatch using lower version of react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am encountering a function not found using useDispatch. Supposedly, I should be using react-redux, unfortunately, my version is 6.0.0 and what's needed is 7.0.0 and above. I'd like to explore useDispatch or related hook to dispatch an action function inside a function component. How do I do this given that I cannot upgrade my react-redux & still use function component?

My alternative is to use class component, but again, I'd like to see this work in function component. Let me know what other details needed.

Here's my code.

```
import React, { useDispatch } from 'react';
import {
    Tooltip,
    IconButton,
    Icon,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { logout } from './auth/store/actions';

const QuickLogout = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip title="Logout" placement="bottom">
        <IconButton className="w-64 h-64" onClick={handleClick}>
            <Icon>exit_to_app</Icon>
        </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default QuickLogout;
```

And here's the error when compiling.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
QuickLogout
webpack-internal:///.....onents/QuickLogout.js:18:75
```

[image]

Edit: I mentioned exploring useDispatch or related hooks given that I cannot upgrade. I felt that this is a gray statement as I really just wanted my code to work. That means, solution is not limited to useDispatch or other hooks. Hence, I chose the answer that did not use useDispatch or hooks because it was plain simple. Apologies for the vague statement. I'll take note on improving my writing skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't upgrade your `react-redux` version to one with the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` React hooks you can still use the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/6.x/api/connect#connect) Higher Order Component to inject `dispatch`, or to even more simply wrap your action creators with a call to `dispatch`.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const QuickLogout = ({ logout }) => { // <-- destructure logout prop
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Logout" placement="bottom">
      <IconButton
        className="w-64 h-64"
        onClick={logout} // <-- assign to click handler
      >
        <Icon>exit_to_app</Icon>
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  logout, // <-- inject logout action as prop already wrapped by dispatch!
};

const ConnectedQuickLogout = connect(
  null, // <-- this is typically mapStateToProps, but we don't need it
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(QuickLogout);

export default ConnectedQuickLogout;
```

If you prefer to keep the code closer to as-is then you can simply connect it to the redux store and a `dispatch` prop is still injected.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const QuickLogout = ({ dispatch }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };

  return (
    <Tooltip title="Logout" placement="bottom">
        <IconButton className="w-64 h-64" onClick={handleClick}>
            <Icon>exit_to_app</Icon>
        </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default connect()(QuickLogout);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and close to my initial code. I made the last part just `export default connect()(QuickLogout);`. I did not know you can use connect in function component ^_^

Comment: @duduwe That is the nice part about React, ***components*** are ***components*** regardless of being class-based or functional, and Higher Order Components simply decorate React components.

Answer (score 4):

React itself doesn't have `useDispatch` in it [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), but it has `useReducer` to eliminate redux for a small project that redux is an overengineering process for them.

On the other hand, new versions of `react-redux` provide new handy hooks which you can make a similar version of those by yourself.

Here is a Tip

> Hooks (React hooks) can only be used in functional component
> HOC (Higher-order component) can be used anywhere

The `connect` function which `react-redux` provides is HOC so it can also be used with both class-base and functional components. It is also a good practice to separate your presentation UI and logic into `representational`s and `container`s, hence there will be no problem for your component to be functional and use all fancy things that could be used in traditional class-component and connect by react-redux.

you **can** also make your custom hook for handling such things in a re-usable manner with less code.

```js
// setup.js
const store = createStore(/* put your reducer and enhancers here */)
export const { dispatch, getState } = store

// hooks.js
import { dispatch, getState } from '~setup.js'

export const useDispatch = () => dispatch
export const useSelector = selector => selector(getState())
// The above useSelector wont cause your component to re-render on data change
```

Then in your component

```
import { useDispatch } from '~hooks.js'
import { logout } from './auth/store/actions'

export default function QuickLogout() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
   const handleClick = () => {
    dispatch(logout())
  }

  return (
    <Tooltip>
        <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
            <Icon>exit_to_app</Icon>
        </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  )
}
```

If you want to know more about custom hooks see [making my own hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

Comment: Thankeee. This is a cool alternative using custom hooks. I'll definitely remember this one. (＾＾)b

Comment: Thanks as well for additional info that connect can be used in functional components.